# Promote subdocument properties to primary document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a `$match` and `$project` in an `aggregate` pipeline that return documents similar to this

```
{
    _id: "KNYBROOK136",
    lastOb : {
        temp : 56
        tzname : "America/New_York"
    }
}

{
    _id: "KNYBROOK45",
    lastOb : {
        temp : 53
        tzname : "America/New_York"
    }
}
```

What can I add to the pipeline to promote these subdocument properties to the top level of each document like this?

```
{
    _id: "KNYBROOK136",
    temp : 56,
    tzname : "America/New_York"
}

{
    _id: "KNYBROOK45",
    temp : 53,
    tzname : "America/New_York"
}
```

Comment: Use two project like second project will be `{"$project":{"_id":"$_id","temp":"$lastOb.temp","tzname":"$lastOb.tzname"}}`

Comment: That's it. I didn't know that you could specify anything other than `1` for the value in a `$project` object. I didn't know you could reference values. Post this as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: can you post sample document?

Comment: It's proprietary, unfortunately. But you could just say that I need to reference property names instead of just using `1`. For example, I am currently saying `"lastOb.temp" : 1` instead of `"temp" : "$lastOb.temp"` as I should be.

Comment: you should used another `project` and write  `"temp" : "$lastOb.temp" ` hope that work fine :)

Comment: Haha. Yes, it did. But if you like, I could give you credit for it if you want to post this as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you missed second `$project` in your aggregation, add this after `$project` :

```
{"$project":{"_id":"$_id","temp":"$lastOb.temp","tzname":"$lastOb.tzname"}}
```